# Laravel select days in a FullCalendar in a modal

Tags: javascript, laravel, fullcalendar, bootstrap-modal

I have a FullCalendar calendar in my Laravel project which, when clicking on an input, opens a modal where the calendar is located. When I open the modal, it does not allow me to select a day, but until I click on the buttons to change the day. month, I would like to know what I am doing wrong or what I should change or add.

Javascript file code:

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendario');

    calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        showNonCurrentDates: true,
        locale: 'es',
        selectable: true,
        editable: true,
        eventColor: 'red',
        eventTextColor: '#fff',
        height: 'auto',
        buttonText: {
            today: 'Hoy',
        },
        eventOverlap: false,
        dateClick: function (info) {
            // Obtiene la fecha seleccionada en el calendario
            var fechaSeleccionada = info.dateStr;
            // Actualiza el valor del campo de entrada con la fecha seleccionada
            document.getElementById("fechaCita").value = fechaSeleccionada;
        },
        dayCellContent: function (info) {
            info.dayNumberText = info.dayNumberText.replace(/^0+/,
                ''); // Eliminar ceros a la izquierda
            return {
                html: '<span class="fc-day-number">' + info.dayNumberText + '</span>'
            };
        },
        dayCellDidMount: function (info) {
            var el = info.el;
            var num = el.querySelector('.fc-day-number');
            if (num) {
                num.style.color = '#000'; // Cambiar color del número a negro
            }
            el.style.backgroundColor = '#fff'; // Cambiar fondo del día a blanco
        },
        dayHeaderContent: function (info) {
            return {
                html: "<span style='color: black'>" + info.text + "</span>"
            };
        },
    });

    calendar.render();

    fechaCita.addEventListener("click", function () {
        var modalEl = document.getElementById('calendarioModal');
        var modal = new bootstrap.Modal(modalEl);
        modal.show();
    });
```

HTML file code:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="calendarioModal" aria-labelledby="modal-fecha-label" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <br>
                        <div id="calendario"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I already tried changing all the options that FullCalendar gives and changing the z-index of the modal but nothing works

Comment: Make sure you run calendar.render(); after modal.show(). Sometimes if the calendar is inside an element which is hidden, it can mess with the formatting and functionality. Try that and let me know if it helps.

Comment: If it is something that I have tried something, I will show you how the modal is opened. fechaCita.addEventListener("click", function () {
        var modalEl = document.getElementById('calendarioModal');
        var modal = new bootstrap.Modal(modalEl);
        modal.show();
        calendar.render();
});